# Display CheckBox in flexgrid when using ownerdraw

Tags: c1flexgrid

Hi am using c1Flexgrid for winforms. I have a form which get data from sql server and it contains both images and bit data type. I have been able to display the images on my c1Flexgrid but it always messes with the checkbox. It does not display the checkbox well anytime row is selected.